# How can I prevent my special symbols to conflict with other global symbols?

Tags: scoping

I am building a tool to manipulate Feynman diagrams and depict them using the `Graph` functionality. A diagram might have the following syntax

```
f=diag[g[a,i[1]],g[b,i[2]],g[i[1],c],g[i[2],d],v[i[1],i[2]]]
```

This is just an example. Now we would like to represent it as a graph.

**First way (using `RuleDelayed`):**

```
Clear[pic]
pic[diag[x__]]:=Module[{i},Graph[List[x]/.{g[i_,j_]:> DirectedEdge[j,i],v[j_,k_]:> UndirectedEdge[j,k]},VertexLabels->"Name",PlotTheme->"Business",ImageSize->300,ImagePadding->10,VertexLabelStyle->Directive[Black,11],GraphHighlight->Cases[List[x],v[i_,j_]:> UndirectedEdge[i,j]]]]
```

Using it

```
pic[f]
i=5;
pic[f]
```

produces

[image]
[image]

Thus we have an expected result and a result with **wrong labels**.

**Second way (using `Rule`)**

```
Clear[i,g,v,f]
f=diag[g[a,i[1]],g[b,i[2]],g[i[1],c],g[i[2],d],v[i[1],i[2]]];
Clear[pic]
pic[diag[x__]]:=Module[{i,j,k},Graph[List[x]/.{g[i_,j_]->DirectedEdge[j,i],v[j_,k_]->UndirectedEdge[j,k]},VertexLabels->"Name",PlotTheme->"Business",ImageSize->300,ImagePadding->10,VertexLabelStyle->Directive[Black,11],GraphHighlight->Cases[List[x],v[i_,j_]->UndirectedEdge[i,j]]]]
```

Now using it

```
pic[f]
i=5;
pic[f]
```

Produces the correct picture only the first time, and **does not work at all second time**.

Comment: `RuleDelayed` solves your problem in the second snippet. It is true that `Rule` treats named pattern as local to the rule. However in the second snippet, the right-hand side gets evaluated to `Times[2, 5]` *before* any replacing takes place. `RuleDelayed` first performs replacements, and then evaluates the expression on the right-hand side of the rule. I am still confused about the first snippet, though.

Comment: I think `SetDelayed` is not relevant here. The confusing part is this: `Clear[i, x]; i = n; Module[{i}, x /. {i_ -> i}] (*n*)`. To be honest, if this is expected behavior I have understood nothing about `Module`.

Comment: OK, the relevant documentation for `Module` is this "Before evaluating expr, Module substitutes new symbols for each of the local variables that appear anywhere in expr except as local variables in scoping constructs." The issue now is that `Rule` is also a scoping construct (with named patterns). Therefore `Module` does not replace the `i` in the `Rule`.

Comment: As a general rule I suggest: Any time you write a rule where the name of the pattern appears on the right-hand side, use `RuleDelayed`. This would be the "canonical way" in my opinion.

Comment: Ok, in the second one the problem is of course again using `Rule` instead of `RuleDelayed`. In the first the problem for the label is that `f` is defined using `i`. Of course, if you later set `i` it will be used for the value of `f`. Mathematica usually evaluates expressions unless being told to hold them.

Comment: @Natas Right, but I am not sure how to hold `i` in the first way.

Comment: Well, once you define it, there is no going back. Of course a more flexible definition of `f` would use `DownValues` and `SetDelayed`.

Comment: The problem is that you are using global variables. Either be very careful that there aren't any conflicts (yeah, right...) or don't use global variables at all. There is no way around this problem.

Comment: @Natas Hmm.. But can you elaborate (possibly as an answer) on what do you mean with a more flexible definition of `f` . The thing is I am doing something similar like you said, but it does not change anything.

Comment: I fear that anything addressing your issue would result again in a wall of text. Perhaps a solution for you would be to `Protect` the special symbols to prevent any assignment to them. There just isn't any easy solution too scoping in programming. If you want to do it right, it takes a lot of time and patience.

Comment: I can identify at least 2 issues in the `Graph` example: 1. 2. `Module` only _sees_ explicit variable: `Clear[a, b, c]; b = 2 a; Module[{a = 2}, b]`, so `Module` just won't help here. `Block` may be a choice for circumventing. 2. Function without `Hold*` attribute evaluates its argument before it's passed into the function. Example: `Clear[f, i]; f[x_] := Block[{i}, Hold[x]]; i = 2; {f[i], f[Unevaluated@i]}`, so your `i` has already evaluated to `5` before passing into the function.

Comment: One possible solution: `Clear[i, pic]; f = diag[g[a, i[1]], g[b, i[2]], g[i[1], c], g[i[2], d], v[i[1], i[2]]];pic[diag[x__]] :=  Graph[{x} /. {g[i_, j_] :> DirectedEdge[j, i], v[j_, k_] :> UndirectedEdge[j, k]}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];i = 5;Block[{i = "i"}, pic[f]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question boils down to: "How can I prevent my special symbols to conflict with other global symbols?"

#### Solution 1: `Block`

With `Block` you can localize your symbols, protecting them from any global assignments. This is the recommended solution. (Note that `Block` is also used in the definition of `pic`.)

```
Clear[pic]
pic[diag[x__]] := 
 Block[{g, v}, 
  Graph[List[x] /. {g[i_, j_] :> DirectedEdge[j, i], 
     v[j_, k_] :> UndirectedEdge[j, k]}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   PlotTheme -> "Business", ImageSize -> 300, ImagePadding -> 10, 
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 11], 
   GraphHighlight -> 
    Cases[List[x], v[i_, j_] :> UndirectedEdge[i, j]]]]
Block[{i, g, v, a, b, c, d},
 f = diag[g[a, i[1]], g[b, i[2]], g[i[1], c], g[i[2], d], 
   v[i[1], i[2]]];
 pic[f]
 ]
```

#### Solution 2: `Protect`

This is a quick and easy solution to your problem. `Protect`ing a symbol means that no one can assign to it. This should probably appear at the top of your notebook.

```
Clear[i, g, v, a, b, c, d];
Protect[i, g, v, a, b, c, d];
f = diag[g[a, i[1]], g[b, i[2]], g[i[1], c], g[i[2], d], v[i[1], i[2]]];
```

#### Solution 3: `Formal` symbols

This is probably a more cumbersome solution, since special symbols are hard to type in Mathematica. However, Mathematica features `Formal` variants of many symbols which cannot be assigned to.

```
Clear[pic]
pic[diag[x__]] := 
 Graph[List[
    x] /. {\[FormalG][i_, j_] :> 
     DirectedEdge[j, i], \[FormalV][j_, k_] :> UndirectedEdge[j, k]}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", PlotTheme -> "Business", ImageSize -> 300, 
  ImagePadding -> 10, VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 11], 
  GraphHighlight -> 
   Cases[List[x], \[FormalV][i_, j_] :> UndirectedEdge[i, j]]]
f = diag[\[FormalG][\[FormalA], \[FormalI][
     1]], \[FormalG][\[FormalB], \[FormalI][
     2]], \[FormalG][\[FormalI][
     1], \[FormalC]], \[FormalG][\[FormalI][
     2], \[FormalD]], \[FormalV][\[FormalI][1], \[FormalI][2]]];
pic[f]
```

(Another possible issue is that now the labels of the graph are the formal symbols.)